# Como verificar se uma variável foi definida no Python?

Tags: python, variáveis

Existe alguma maneira de verificar se uma variável foi definida ou não em Python?

Comment: Quem deu o negativo, pode mostrar qual é o problema com a pergunta?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Se a variável é local basicamente é isto:

```
if 'variavel' in locals():
```

Se quer saber se ela existe entre as globais:

```
if 'variavel' in globals():
```

E finalmente se ela é membro de algum objeto:

```
if hasattr(objeto, 'variavel'):
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Reflection/Variable.py).

Estas são as formas diretas para verificar a existência da variável. Existem outras formas que poderão ajudar a descobrir a existência. O QMechanic73 descobriu uma e postou na resposta dele que a função `dir()` que pode listar variáveis em escopo ou atributos de objetos disponíveis. Quaisquer outras formas não verificam a existência. Existem formas que gerarão uma exceção o que tecnicamente não é verificar a existência e sim tomar a ações após tentar acessar uma variável não existente.

Comment: No primeiro, segundo e terceiro exemplo, você usa 'variavel' como string porque ele verifica se existe essa `key` em `locals`?

Comment: Basicamente é isto. Python como a grande parte das linguagens dinâmicas não tem variáveis de verdade como em outros linguagens mais concretas. Não há um espaço na memória que este nome se referencia de forma direta. Sua observação é pertinente quando dá uma indicação que as variáveis no fundo são chaves de uma estrutura *hash*. Um dos motivos para o desempenho destas linguagens serem inferior. Mas existem linguagens como Clipper/Harbour ou Lua (se não estou enganado) que conseguem alocar variáveis diretamente e proporciona performance melhor - ainda que não comparável à linguagens estáticas.

Comment: Evidentemente este tipo de verificação não é possível em variáveis "reais", este tipo de verificação só pode ser feita pelo compilador porque a variável desaparece após a compilação.

Comment: Esse `in` funciona do mesmo jeito que no `javascript`?

Comment: Essencialmente sim. Não sei se toda a semântica é igual mas a base é igual ao operador `in` do JS.

Comment: dei um "-1" por que a informação "Pode ainda verificar se ela tem algum valor, se não tiver, se for None, ela não existe" está completamente incorreta. Os casos que você lista acima são suficientes para verificar se uma variável existe - `if variavel is None` vai dar uma exceão de NameError se a variável de fato não existir.

Comment: @jsbueno você tem toda razão. Obrigado por me alertar. Corrigido.

Comment: O @jsbueno está certo. tentar fazer essa verificação direta gera um erro

Comment: Fui aconselhado por questão de coerência a não verificar se a variável não existe. Um amigo meu disse "variável inexistente é variável inexistente". Ele me aconselhou a deixar a variável setada como `None`, já que eu quero usá-la, porém ela ainda não possa ter nenhum valor :)

Comment: Faz sentido. Na maior parte dos casos verificar se a variável existe mostra um problema no código. Alguns dirão até que uma variável poder não existir é um problema na linguagem :)

Comment: @QMechanic73 pronto, coloquei na resposta sua descoberta. Se achar novos meios, me avise para chamar a atenção na resposta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 6):

Uma outra forma alternativa é a função [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#dir):

> Sem argumentos, retorna uma lista de nomes do escopo atual. Com argumento, retorna uma lista de atributos válidos para esse objeto.

Veja os exemplos abaixo:

```
# Exemplo 1
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self, nome, peso):
        self.nome = nome
        self.peso = peso

pessoa = Pessoa('Wallace', 50)

if 'nome' in dir(pessoa):
    # "nome" existe na classe "Pessoa"
    pass        
if 'peso' in dir(pessoa):
    # "peso" existe na classe "Pessoa"
    pass

# Exemplo 2
nome = 'Wallace'
peso = 50

if 'nome' in dir():
    # "nome" existe nesse escopo
    pass
if 'peso' in dir():
    # "peso" existe nesse escopo
    pass
```

Uma outra forma é tratar a exceção [`NameError`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/exceptions.html#NameError), ela é gerada quando um nome *local* ou *global* não é encontrado.

```py
def foo():
    try:
        nome = 'Wallace'
        nome =+ idade  # A variável idade não está definida
    except NameError:  # Captura a exceção
        idade = '50'   # Define a variável

    return nome + idade   

print (foo())
```

Answer (score 2):

Outra maneira simples é usar uma exceção:

```
try:
    print(name)
except NameError:
    print("name não existe")
```