# Qual o equivalente de 'isset' do PHP em Python

Tags: php, python, variáveis

Em PHP, se eu quero saber se uma variável foi iniciada, eu uso `isset`.

Como posso fazer o mesmo em Python?

Comment: Isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50206/101

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Nativamente não tem.**

Se a necessidade é checar somente se a variável existe eu recomendo iniciar todas variáveis com algum valor, como `None` ou `False` (dependendo da necessidade), não tem porque criar algo complexo para isso (veja no final da respostas os exemplos).

É preciso entender que o `isset` do PHP **faz bem mais do que checar se uma variável existe**, ele também verifica se uma chave existe ou até mesmo pode checar se uma string contém um minimo de cateteres, o que irá permitir checar se a variável existe e checar a string ao mesmo tempo, então logo lhe digo de cara que exatamente como `isset` do PHP não tem no python.

Claro que se o intuito é checar uma variavel apenas você poderia simplesmente tentar algo como:

```
try:
    minhavar
    print('Variavel definida')
except NameError:
    print('Variavel não definida')
```

Você também poderia usar `globals()` para checar as variaveis definidas no escopo e criar uma função propria, algo como:

```
def isset(nameVar):
    return nameVar in globals()
```

> Veja mais sobre isto nesta pergunta:
>
> - [Como verificar se uma variável foi definida no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50206/3635)

E o uso seria:

```
if isset('variavel'):
    print('Variavel definida')
else:
    print('Variavel não definida')
```

Mas é como eu disse, o `isset` do PHP tem um comportamento bem especifico, logo para cada coisa do `isset` teria que criar um "teste", exemplos de funcionalidades do PHP:

```
//Se a variavel for uma string, verifica se existe e se ela contém 3 caracteres
//o index de uma string começa pelo zero, ou seja o primeiro caractere é o zero, o segundo vai ser o 1 e assim por diante
if (isset($foo[2])) {
     ...
}

//Checando se uma variavel tem acesso a uma propriedade especifica (o valor não pode ser nulo)
if (isset($foo->bar)) {
     ...
}

//Checando se uma variavel de array tem acesso a uma chave e esta chave não é um valor nulo
if (isset($foo['bar'])) {
     ...
}
```

Note que mesmo que uma variavel, chave ou propriedade de um objeto existam o `isset` vai retornar como `false` no PHP, isso porque `NULL` é unica exceção.

Seriam comportamentos um pouco complexo de transportar para o Python, não é impossível, mas vai depender da sua necessidade, não há motivos para criar uma função "monstruosa" no código se não vai usar tudo, **eu pessoalmente** em Python optaria por definir tudo, logo no começo do script ou do escopo de um `def` setando com `None` talvez, por exemplo:

```
foo = None
bar = None
baz = None
```

e checaria assim:

```
if foo is None:
    print('foo é nula')
else:
    print('foo foi definida')
```

Pode simplificar para:

```
foo = bar = baz = None
```

Ou pode usar o *unpack*, seria assim, se tem 3 variáveis use `*3`, como nestes exemplo:

```
foo, bar, baz = (None,)*3
```

Se desejar setar como `False`:

```
foo, bar, baz = (False,)*3
```

Isto ajuda a evitar uma certa repetição de códigos

Comment: Qual a diferença ou vantagem de usar da forma *unpack*, visto que o exemplo de cima faz a mesma coisa de forma mais legível?

Comment: @DiegoSouza nenhuma vantagem no caso especifico, mas no uso dinâmico talvez com dicionários seria mais interessante. Só citei mesmo porque achei interessante.

Comment: @AnselmoBlancoDominguez  Obrigado pela edição, ela foi pertinente.

Comment: É bom lembrar que em `a, b, c = [{}] * 3` as variáveis `a`, `b` e `c` apontam para o mesmo dicionário, então se for fazer isso, seria melhor fazer `a, b, c = {}, {}, {}` para evitar confusão com as referências. PS: mencionei isso por conta dos comentários, não da resposta.

Comment: @fernandosavio sim, pq são referencias, creio que deva ter uma resposta sobre, semelhante ao caso de quando declara valores padrões em `def`, existem os tipos mutáveis e imutáveis.

Answer (score 2):

As *built-in functions* [locals()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#locals) e [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#globals), apontam as tabelas de símbolos local e global, respectivamente.

Você pode verificar se a variável

> nome_var

existe nesses dicionários da seguinte forma:

```
if 'nome_var' in locals():
    print('variável local')
```

ou

```
'nome_var' in globals()
```

Prático, porém menos recomendado - por ser uma função criada principalmente para uso no ambiente interativo do python - seria utilizar a *built-in function* [dir()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#dir), que aponta para uma lista de nomes disponíveis no escopo atual.

```
'nome_var' in dir()
```