# Erro básico em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Criei este script, mas está dando esse seguinte erro:

```
print('Choices\n1-Option 1\n2-Option 2\n3-Option 3')


if choose =='1':
    print('The account is 5+5')
elif choose =='2':
    print('The account is 6+6')
elif choose =='3':
    print('The account is 7+9')


else:
    print('You choose none options')
```

Erro:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
>  if choice =='1':
>  NameError: name 'choice' is not defined
> ```

Alguém pode me dizer o que está errado? Sendo que há alguns dias o programa executava normalmente? Aliás, já rodei em python, pycharm e ide online, e nada de funcionar

Comment: Posso editar sua pergunta? Tem parte sem formatação o código Python.

Comment: Cadê o código completo? Você declarou o choice antes?

Comment: @MauryDeveloper a tag [python] na pergunta já aplica o highlight na postagem, não precisa adicionar explicito neste caso com \`\`\`pyton, basta a tag na pergunta que o sistema faz o resto.

Comment: Ok. Obrigado pela informações.

Answer (score 3):

A variável choice não foi definida, não existe, não tem porque o código funcionar, o código não tem como adivinhar o que você escreveu dentro de uma string em um print:

```
print('Choices\n1-Option 1\n2-Option 2\n3-Option 3')
```

O que deve estar faltando é o `input` para pegar o que o usuário entrar no terminal/cmd/etc, provavelmente você queria alguma coisa como:

```
print('Choices\n1-Option 1\n2-Option 2\n3-Option 3')

choose = input()

if choose =='1':
    print('The account is 5+5')
elif choose =='2':
    print('The account is 6+6')
elif choose =='3':
    print('The account is 7+9')
else:
    print('You choose none options')
```

Comment: Mais informações de como declarar uma variável em Python: https://www.guru99.com/variables-in-python.html

Comment: @MauryDeveloper um tutorial inteiro para ensinar como usar o `=`? Acho um pouco de exagero, mas ok, quem sabe vale a dica. Ainda sim uma boa fonte seria a documentação oficial. Sobre variaveis iria um pouco mais longe, porque o tutorial ai tá meio fraco (apesar de falar algo importante como o global), alguns links que podem lhe interessar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/307826/3635 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240667/3635 (apesar de este segundo ser mais sobre argumentos, ainda sim fala sobre o imutaveis e os não)

Comment: Eu aprendi Python nessa página,por isso mandei,eu queria só ajuda. E obrigado pelos links vou ver-lo e estudar.